# Splitting a string with curly braces as delimeters?

Tags: javascript, regex, split

```
'{5}<blah>{0}</blah>'
```

i want to turn that into:

```
['{5}', '<blah>', '{0}', '</blah>']
```

i currently use: `________.split(/({.*?})/);`

but this fails when curly brace is the first character as in the case:

```
'{0}<blah>'
```

which gets turned into:
`['', '{0}', '<blah>']` ... a 3 element array, not a 2

what's wrong with my regex?

Thanks!

Comment: Try removing the parenthesis, and making this a one-or-more match.  For example, /{.+?}/.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your regex, but there's an issue with how you're using split. Split returns an array based on a delimiter, so if the delimiter is FIRST, it gives you the stuff to the left and right of the split item.

Just check to see if the first item == '' and remove it if it is.

Comment: Mine too! Honor doesn't exist on teh Interwebs ;)

Comment: I'm a fast typer, and I'm a pretty prominent psychic in the midwest. 1 + 2 == stolen SO responses!

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
split(/((?!^)\{.*?\})/)
```

The negative lookahead -- `(?!^)` -- succeeds iff the match does not start at the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 1):

What do you think of:

```
'{5}<blah>{0}</blah>'.split(/{([^}]+)}/g)
```

The value of the curly blocks are every 2 items from the item 1.